# How to measure the load balancing in OpenMP of GCC

Tags: gcc, openmp, load-balancing

I am writing a program with GCC OpenMP. And Now I want to check if my OpenMP program has good balanced load. Are there some methods to do this?

BTW, what is the good method to measure the load balancing? (I don't want to use Intel VTune tool.)

I am not sure if this is the right place for my question, any replies are appreciated. And I make the question more detailed.

I am writting OpenMP programs under GCC compiler. And I want to know the details about the overhead of GCC-OpenMP. My concerns are given below.
1) What is the good way to optimize my OpenMP program? There are many aspects that will affect the performance, such as load balancing, locality, scheduling overhead, synchronization, and so on. In which order should I check these aspects.

2) I want to know how to get the load balancing of my application under GCC-OpenMP. How to instrument my application and the OpenMP runtime to extract the load balancing feature?

3) I guess OpenMP will spend some time on scheduling. What runtime APIs should I instrument to get the value of scheduling overhead?

4) Can I measure the time that OpenMP program spend on synchronization, critical, lock and atomic operations?

Comment: What's your definition of load balance here?

Comment: If every thread/worker do the same amount of work share(like iteration chunk or task)? And the amount is measured with time uinit.

Comment: Why not measure the work done on each thread then? Profiling OpenMP itself is somewhat complicated.

Comment: You mean, let each thread count the time that it spent on its task. It is ok to get the amount work of each thread. And then, how could I find the reason if the load balancing is bad. I.E., what time it spends on? (I guess maybe synchronization, lock, ....)

Comment: It would be a lot easier to answer you question if you gave a specific code example you want to profile. I realize that may not be general enough but starting with a specific example may make it a lot easier to generalize later.

Answer (score 1):

[OmpP](http://www.ompp-tool.com/home.html) is a profiler for OpenMP applications. The profiler reports percentage of the execution spent in critical section and also measures the imbalance at the implicit barriers of different OpenMP constructs

A different approach to measure load imbalance would be to use the [likwid-perfctr](https://github.com/RRZE-HPC/likwid/wiki/likwid-perfctr) tool. The tool reports the number of instructions executed in each core. For applications with the same amount of work per thread, a variance in the number of instructions executed in different cores is an indicator of load imbalance.